# How to implement custom identity authorization with AWS Amplify (Flutter or JS)

Tags: javascript, ios, amazon-web-services, flutter, aws-amplify

In the iOS AWSCore library one can authorize bespoke third-party auth systems into an AWS identity pool roughly as follows:

```swift
let myIdProvider = MyCustomIdProvider()
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.USWest2, identityProvider: myIdProvider)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USWest2, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)!
// which is then used for things like S3 access...

// The custom provider class...
class MyCustomIdProvider : AWSCognitoCredentialsProviderHelper {
   override func token() -> AWSTask<NSString> {
       // Do the verification here
   }
}
```

I want to move this code to a cross-platform solution (in Dart/Flutter ideally but happy with a JS solution for now). How can I accomplish that in Amplify?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? A translation of your code into Flutter/Dart?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following steps, in short, you really not required the above code when working with AWS Cognito amplify API this API provides abstraction and make your life simple.

1. You need to create an Identity pool

[image]

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-an-application-with-aws-amplify-amazon-cognito-and-an-openid-connect-identity-provider/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html

2. The Amplify Framework uses Amazon Cognito as the main authentication provider. Amazon Cognito is a robust user directory service that handles user registration, authentication, account recovery & other operations. In this tutorial, you'll learn how to add authentication to your application using Amazon Cognito and username/password login.

Following is an example in `react.js` but you can use the same in your code as its using simple JavaScript, you can download and add your user pool details in `config.json` and check in local

**Code example:**

- https://github.com/vaquarkhan/aws-cognito-amplify-reactjs-poc/tree/main/src
- https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/